# How to secure an Android Application PIN code screen from bruteforce locally

Tags: android, security, frida

I'm trying to understand the specifics of securing a PIN code / lock screen within an Android application. (Example: https://github.com/thealeksandr/PFLockScreen-Android)
Take a banking app, for example, often they will request a PIN code to sign back into your account.
My question is how does one secure this PIN code check on the assumption that is handled entirely locally or is this not possible.

My thoughts on this are that the PIN code could easily be stored in the Android Keystore, but wouldn't the PIN function its self still be vulnerable to brute-forcing through the usage of tools like Frida.
Even if an anti brute force check was made couldn't Frida hook this and alter the counter / just reopen the app over and over?

I understand the threat model for this is quite limited, however, it's been making me think for a while as I can't see any way of securing it without using some form of server-side validation.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to build in captcha. To prevent brute force attacks in my opinion using a captcha is the best solution.

Comment: Banking app is easy. Such apps are always online, hence you can check on server side how many false attempts has been made and force the user to wait an increasing time-span between each attempt.

Comment: The question quite clearly states multiple times this is about local bruteforce attempts and not server side.

Answer (score 0):

Store it locally as a one-way hash (e.g. SHA256). Upon login, you compute the hash of what they typed, compared it to the stored, hashed value.